# How to send .pfx file and it's password while calling external API in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, python-requests

I am calling an external API in python, in which I have to send a .pfx file and it's respective password but I am unable to figure out how to send it.

This is my existing code:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import requests, os, sys, json


def callExternalAPI(payload):
    try:

        url = 'externalAPIURL'

        headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Accept': 'application/json'
        }

        params = {
            'client_id': 'uniqueClientId',
            'client_secret': 'uniqueClientSecret',
        }

        auth = HTTPBasicAuth('userId', 'password')

        data = json.dumps(payload)

        response = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers, params=params, auth=auth, cert=('path_of_.pfx_file', '.pfx_password'))

        return response.json()

    except Exception as err:
        exc_type, exc_obj, exc_tb = sys.exc_info()
        fname = os.path.split(exc_tb.tb_frame.f_code.co_filename)[1]
        print(exc_type, fname, exc_tb.tb_lineno)
        return str(err)

payload = {
    "description": "description",
    "status": "status",
}

externalAPIResponse = callExternalAPI(payload)

print(externalAPIResponse)
```

But this code is not working. I have .crt file, .key file, password. I just wanted to know whether my method to call the external API is correct or not.

Comment: That depends entirely on the external API.